# Angular instances are doubled when bootstrapping them by inserting build scripts in the script tag

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular12

When I insert angular build scripts with `document.createElement('script')` angular instances double. It works when there are more than one build. You can see it in the sandbox console: there are four `console.log()`.

[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/load-angular-g3h2s8?file=%2Fapp-c.js&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpttr8l20006356hpz3739xj%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpttr8l20002356hzzvxvbmm%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpttr8l20003356hx32j5t5c%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpttr8l20005356hcle3r3y8%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpttr8l20002356hzzvxvbmm%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpttr8l20002356hzzvxvbmm%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clptts8f70002356h3og7i6vq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp-c.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clptts8f70002356h3og7i6vq%2522%257D%252C%2522clpttr8l20005356hcle3r3y8%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpttr8l20004356hjdad6pua%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpttr8l20005356hcle3r3y8%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpttr8l20004356hjdad6pua%2522%257D%252C%2522clpttr8l20003356hx32j5t5c%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpttr8l20003356hx32j5t5c%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Here is my build script:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const concat = require('concat');

const uniqueName = app-c;
const uniqueComponentPath = ./dist/app/${uniqueName}.js;

(async function build() {
   const files = [
    './dist/app/runtime.js',
    './dist/app/polyfills.js',
    './dist/app/main.js'
   ].filter((x) => fs.pathExistsSync(x));
   await fs.ensureFile(uniqueComponentPath);
   await concat(files, uniqueComponentPath);
})();

"build": "ng build --output-hashing none && node build.js"
```